# How do I define a local path in gradle without compromising my repo?

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I would like to define a path on my localhost that points to a library dependency of one of my modules. I need to define this path without compromising my git repository. That is, the path should be defined in some local properties/settings file.

My question is, where should I define this path, and how do I reference it in my module's build.gradle file?

Comment: Is it undesirable to put that library in your project, or better yet, in some public repo?

Comment: It's complicated, but the short answer is yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to define a build property outside of source control then it's best to place it in *USER_HOME*/.gradle/gradle.properties. See the [Gradle docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties) for more on build properties, where they can be defined, and resolution order.

Properties can then be referenced as they are defined in the gradle.properties file.